# remove (or hide) div B if div A is empty in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove (or hide) div B if div A is empty. Doing so would clean up the screen a bit.

```js
if ( $('#textDiv').text()=='' ) {
  $('#newPlayer').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "textDiv"></div>

<div id = "newPlayer">blah blah"</div>
```

Comment: This should work. What's the problem? Put it inside `$(function () {})`. Is there any issue or question?

Comment: Got it. You're right!

Comment: I'll put that as an answer, feel free to accept it. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is fine just wrap it inside `$(function(){});` or `$(document).ready(function(){});` or use it at bottom of page

```js
$(function(){

setInterval(function(){if ( $('#textDiv').text()=='' ) {
  $('#newPlayer').hide();
}},1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "textDiv"></div>

<div id = "newPlayer">blah blah"</div>
```

Comment: why use setInterval?

Comment: to make it visible

Comment: setInterval is an overkill

Comment: what do you mean

Answer (score 1):

Your code is lacking `document`'s `ready` function. Putting your code inside the `ready` event of the `document` will make it work. Also, use `.trim()` to check the real emptiness.

```js
$(function() {
  if ($('#textDiv').text().trim() == '') {
    $('#newPlayer').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textDiv"></div>
<div id="newPlayer">blah blah"</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put your code inside $(document).ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $('#textDiv').text()=='' ) {
      $('#newPlayer').hide();
    }
})
```